# Getting text content with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have some HTML like this:

```
<dd class="price">
    <sup class="symbol">&#36;</sup><span class="dollars">58</span><sup class="cents">.00</sup>
</dd>
```

What's the xpath to get $58.00 back as one string?

I'm using PHP:

```
$xpath = '?????';
$result = $xml->xpath($xpath);
echo $result[0];   // want this to show $58.00, possible?
```

Answer (score 3):

These are valid in your case, check for more detail the links below;

```
$html = '<dd class="price">
            <sup class="symbol">&#36;</sup><span class="dollars">58</span><sup class="cents">.00</sup>
         </dd>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($html);
$xpt = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpt->query('//dd[@class="price"]') as $node) {
    // outputs: $58.00
    echo trim($node->nodeValue);
}
// or
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
$res1 = $xml->xpath('//dd[@class="price"]/sup');
$res2 = $xml->xpath('//dd[@class="price"]/span');
// outputs: $58.00
printf('%s%s%s', (string) $res1[0], (string) $res2[0], (string) $res1[1]);
```

1. [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
2. [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
3. [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

`data()` will return all contents inside the current context. Try

```
//dd/data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us your code so I don't know what platform you're using.  If you have something that can evaluate non-node XPath expressions, then you can use this:

```
string(//dd[@class = 'price'])
```

if not, you can select the node,

```
//dd[@class = 'price']
```

and the API you're using should have a way of getting the inner text value of the selected node.